# Installing RVM seems to have stopped my cucumber tests running on sauce labs

Tags: ruby, cucumber, rvm, capybara, saucelabs

After I installed RVM (A requirement for another project I am working on at the same time) I can no longer run my cucumber tests against SauceLabs. I have got RVM using system ruby (1.8.7 p374) and all my required gems are installed correctly.

*I will attach the gem list at the bottom*

So when I run the following command, in my folder containing the tests and saucelabs.rb file, ./sauce_labs.rb many I get the following errors:

```
Logging to Windows XP-iehta-8.html ...
Logging to Windows 7-iehta-9.html ...
Logging to Windows 7-iehta-10.html ...
Logging to Windows 8.1-iehta-11.html ...
Logging to Windows 7-firefox-latest.html ...
Logging to Mac 10.8-safari-6.html ...
Logging to Windows 7-googlechrome-latest.html ...
no such file to load -- rake (LoadError)
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/rake/server_task.rb:2:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/rake/server_task.rb:2
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/client.rb:21:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/client.rb:21
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-2.3.2/lib/sauce/selenium.rb:1:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-2.3.2/lib/sauce/selenium.rb:1
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-2.3.2/lib/sauce/capybara.rb:4:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-2.3.2/lib/sauce/capybara.rb:4
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-cucumber-2.3.1/lib/sauce/cucumber.rb:4:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvmno such file to load -- rake (LoadError)
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/rake/server_task.rb:2:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/rake/server_task.rb:2
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/client.rb:21:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/client.rb:21
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-2.3.2/lib/sauce/selenium.rb:1:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-2.3.2/lib/sauce/selenium.rb:1
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-2.3.2/lib/sauce/capybara.rb:4:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-2.3.2/lib/sauce/capybara.rb:4
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-cucumber-2.3.1/lib/sauce/cucumber.rb:4:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-cucumber-2.3.1/lib/sauce/cucumber.rb:4
/Users/donovan.greef/Sites/announcements/tests/features/support/env.rb:33:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/Sites/announcements/tests/features/support/env.rb:33
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:137:in `load'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:137:in `load_code_file'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:180:in `load_file'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `load_files!'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:182:in `load_step_definitions'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:41:in `run!'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/cucumber:14
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/cucumber:23
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15
no such file to load -- rake (LoadError)
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/rake/server_task.rb:2:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/rake/server_task.rb:2
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/client.rb:21:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/client.rb:21
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-2.3.2/lib/sauce/selenium.rb:1:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-2.3.2/lib/sauce/selenium.rb:1
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-2.3.2/lib/sauce/capybara.rb:4:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-2.3.2/lib/sauce/capybara.rb:4
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-cucumber-2.3.1/lib/sauce/cucumber.rb:4:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-cucumber-2.3.1/lib/sauce/cucumber.rb:4
/Users/donovan.greef/Sites/announcements/tests/features/support/env.rb:33:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/Sites/announcements/tests/features/support/env.rb:33
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:137:in `load'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:137:in `load_code_file'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:180:in `load_file'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `load_files!'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:182:in `load_step_definitions'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:41:in `run!'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/cucumber:14
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/cucumber:23
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15
no such file to load -- rake (LoadError)
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/rake/server_task.rb:2:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/rake/server_task.rb:2
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/client.rb:21:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/client.rb:21
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-2.3.2/lib/sauce/selenium.rb:1:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-2.3.2/lib/sauce/selenium.rb:1
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-2.3.2/lib/sauce/capybara.rb:4:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-2.3.2/lib/sauce/capybara.rb:4
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-cucumber-2.3.1/lib/sauce/cucumber.rb:4:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-cucumber-2.3.1/lib/sauce/cucumber.rb:4
/Users/donovan.greef/Sites/announcements/tests/features/support/env.rb:33:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/Sites/announcements/tests/features/support/env.rb:33
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:137:in `load'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:137:in `load_code_file'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:180:in `load_file'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `load_files!'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cno such file to load -- rake (LoadError)
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/rake/server_task.rb:2:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/rake/server_task.rb:2
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/client.rb:21:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/client.rb:21
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-2.3.2/lib/sauce/selenium.rb:1:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-2.3.2/lib/sauce/selenium.rb:1
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-2.3.2/lib/sauce/capybara.rb:4:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-2.3.2/lib/sauce/capybara.rb:4
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-cucumber-2.3.1/lib/sauce/cucumber.rb:4:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvmucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:182:in `load_step_definitions'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:41:in `run!'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/cucumber:14
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/cucumber:23
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15
/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-cucumber-2.3.1/lib/sauce/cucumber.rb:4
/Users/donovan.greef/Sites/announcements/tests/features/support/env.rb:33:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/Sites/announcements/tests/features/support/env.rb:33
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:137:in `load'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:137:in `load_code_file'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:180:in `load_file'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `load_files!'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:182:in `load_step_definitions'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:41:in `run!'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/cucumber:14
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/cucumber:23
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15
/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-cucumber-2.3.1/lib/sauce/cucumber.rb:4
/Users/donovan.greef/Sites/announcements/tests/features/support/env.rb:33:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/Sites/announcements/tests/features/support/env.rb:33
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:137:in `load'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:137:in `load_code_file'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:180:in `load_file'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `load_files!'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:182:in `load_step_definitions'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:41:in `run!'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/cucumber:14
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/cucumber:23
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15
no such file to load -- rake (LoadError)
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/rake/server_task.rb:2:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/rake/server_task.rb:2
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/client.rb:21:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/client.rb:21
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-2.3.2/lib/sauce/selenium.rb:1:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-2.3.2/lib/sauce/selenium.rb:1
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-2.3.2/lib/sauce/capybara.rb:4:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-2.3.2/lib/sauce/capybara.rb:4
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-cucumber-2.3.1/lib/sauce/cucumber.rb:4:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-cucumber-2.3.1/lib/sauce/cucumber.rb:4
/Users/donovan.greef/Sites/announcements/tests/features/support/env.rb:33:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/Sites/announcements/tests/features/support/env.rb:33
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:137:in `load'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:137:in `load_code_file'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:180:in `load_file'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `load_files!'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:182:in `load_step_definitions'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:41:in `run!'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/cucumber:14
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/cucumber:23
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15
no such file to load -- rake (LoadError)
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/rake/server_task.rb:2:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/rake/server_task.rb:2
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/client.rb:21:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/client.rb:21
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-2.3.2/lib/sauce/selenium.rb:1:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-2.3.2/lib/sauce/selenium.rb:1
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-2.3.2/lib/sauce/capybara.rb:4:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-2.3.2/lib/sauce/capybara.rb:4
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-cucumber-2.3.1/lib/sauce/cucumber.rb:4:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sauce-cucumber-2.3.1/lib/sauce/cucumber.rb:4
/Users/donovan.greef/Sites/announcements/tests/features/support/env.rb:33:in `require'
/Users/donovan.greef/Sites/announcements/tests/features/support/env.rb:33
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:137:in `load'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:137:in `load_code_file'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:180:in `load_file'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `load_files!'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:182:in `load_step_definitions'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:41:in `run!'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/cucumber-1.2.3/bin/cucumber:14
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/cucumber:23
/Users/donovan.greef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15
```

I have tried the following to resolve this:

- Install Rake gem (Installed fine but still got the same error)
- Tried installing rails (versions Latest, 2.1.2 and 2.0.0, all failed saying active support requires ruby 1.9.3 - which is not an option at present)
- Tried to find out how to turn off the rake load but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated as I am now fresh out of ideas.

Thank you in advance.

Gem List:

- builder (3.2.0)

  - bundler (1.3.5)
  - capybara (1.1.4)
  - childprocess (0.3.9)
  - cmdparse (2.0.5)
  - commander (4.1.3)
  - cucumber (1.2.3)
  - diff-lcs (1.2.1)
  - eventmachine (1.0.3)
  - faye-websocket (0.4.7)
  - ffi (1.5.0)
  - gherkin (2.11.6)
  - highline (1.6.16)
  - http_parser.rb (0.5.3)
  - json (1.7.7)
  - mime-types (1.21)
  - multi_json (1.7.1)
  - net-http-persistent (2.8)
  - net-ssh (2.6.6)
  - net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0)
  - nokogiri (1.5.9)
  - parallel (0.6.2)
  - parallel_tests (0.10.1)
  - poltergeist (1.0.2)
  - rack (1.5.2)
  - rack-test (0.6.2)
  - rest-client (1.6.7)
  - rspec (2.13.0)
  - rspec-core (2.13.1)
  - rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
  - rspec-mocks (2.13.0)
  - rubyzip (0.9.9)
  - sauce (2.3.2)
  - sauce-cucumber (2.3.1)
  - selenium-webdriver (2.31.0)
  - websocket (1.0.7)
  - xpath (0.1.4)

Comment: do you have a `Gemfile` (if yes is `rake` in there?)

Comment: Rake is not in the gem file. However I have installed rake gem anyway. It is not required for the project. The project is not in Ruby either, It is just my cucumber-capybara tests that are in ruby.

Comment: I had installed rake before producing the gem list in the main question. This was returned so I assume rake is all good 

Successfully installed rake-10.1.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rake-10.1.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for rake-10.1.0...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `Gemfile` with `cucumber`, this makes gem `rubygems-bundler` detect it and automatically load `Bundler.setup` which restricts gems to only those that are defined in `Gemfile` and their dependencies, unfortunately `selenium-webdriver` uses the `rake` gem but does not define it as dependency (http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/rb/build.desc#25).

There are two ways to fix it:

1. Add `rake` to `Gemfile` and `bundle install` this should fix the imediate problem - also report a bug for `selenium-webdriver` for the missing dependency => http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/list
2. Disable the `rubygems-bundler` gem to work with unrestricted gem list

   ```
   NOEXEC_DISABLE=1 ./sauce_labs.rb
   ```

   (always highest version will be loaded instead of those specified in Gemfile and dependencies).

Comment: Option 1 is by far the better option as you still have control over the gems in your list. but Cheers for that help. Will log a bug shortly :)